# SQL Logic to solve a one to many summarization problem

Tags: sql, logic, apache-superset

I have a logic problem to solve, and I'm on it for about a week!

I'm working on a Apache Superset visualization witch a have 1 table with donations:

**Donations:**

| Entity Name | Donator Name | Amount of Donations | People Helped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Entity 1 | Donator 1 | 100 kg | 100 |
| Entity 1 | Donator 1 | 100 kg | 100 |
| Entity 1 | Donator 1 | 100 kg | 100 |
| Entity 1 | Donator 2 | 200 kg | 100 |
| Entity 2 | Donator 2 | 200 kg | 50 |

I'm working on a valid SQL sentence that catches the number of people helped filtering either by entity, donator or without any filter.

The people helped cannot be duplicated, they are a specific amount of people for a determined entity, witch can receive donations from N donators, and a donator can send donations to N entities.

Example:

- When looking without any filter, I need that the number of people helped must be 150
- When filtering Entity 1, I need that the number of people helped must be 100
- When filtering Donator 2, I need that the number of people helped must be 150.

This project is running on a Apache Superset Project, but I believe that my problem is about logic, and not the tool.

I hope that my question was clear enough!

I tried numerous temptations of creating a new table, distincts selects ans group bys, but I was always duplicating and not achieving the correct logic.

**Edit:**

I have on disposition other tables that can be consulted, such as:

| Entity Name | People Helped |
| --- | --- |
| Entity 1 | 100 |
| Entity 2 | 50 |

And the Apache Superset, at least as far as I know, apply the filter by Entity Name or Donator Name, so I need that the table to be used must have both columns, and the summarization have to achieve the goals.

Comment: If you have no filter, why would the number of people helped be 150 and not 450? Your data says there are 450 people being helped